# Missing required parameter for [Route: rekap.laba] [URI: rekapan/laba1/{tanggal}] [Missing parameter: tanggal]

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, show

Hello i have a problem in my code to show a detail from data-tables, the error say "Missing required parameter for [Route: rekap.laba] [URI: rekapan/laba1/{tanggal}] [Missing parameter: tanggal]"
i don't know how to fix it,
this is the button blade

```
<a href="{{ route('rekap.laba', $penjualan->tanggal) }}"  id="detail" class="btn btn-sm btn-info" data-tooltip="tooltip" 
                      data-placement="bottom" title="Detail Laba" ><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i></a>
```

this is theroute

```
Route::get('rekapan/laba1/{tanggal}', '\App\Http\Controllers\TransaksiController@labaReport')->name('rekap.laba')->middleware('admin');
```

this is the controller

```
public function labaReport($tanggal)
    {
        $transaksis = Transaksi::leftJoin('produks', 'produks.id', '=', 'transaksis.produk_id')
        ->leftJoin('daftar_pelanggans', 'daftar_pelanggans.id', '=', 'transaksis.daftar_pelanggan_id')
        ->select('transaksis.daftar_pelanggan_id', 'produks.harga_jual', 'produks.harga_beli', 'produks.nama_barang', 'produks.kode_barang', 'transaksis.kode_transaksi', 'transaksis.total_barang', 'transaksis.created_at', DB::raw('sum(total_barang) as total_beli'), DB::raw('count(produk_id) as produklist'))
        ->groupBy('transaksis.kode_transaksi', 'produks.harga_jual', 'transaksis.created_at', 'produks.harga_beli', 'produks.nama_barang', 'produks.kode_barang', 'transaksis.total_barang', 'transaksis.daftar_pelanggan_id')
        ->where(DB::raw('DATE(transaksis.created_at)', '=', $tanggal))
        ->get();
        return view('pages.rekapan.keuntungan', compact('transaksis'));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

to correctly add the parameter, change:

```
<a href="{{ route('rekap.laba', $penjualan->tanggal) }}"  id="detail" class="btn btn-sm btn-info" data-tooltip="tooltip" 
                      data-placement="bottom" title="Detail Laba" ><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i></a>
```

to:

```
<a href="{{ route('rekap.laba', ['tanggal' => $penjualan->tanggal]) }}"  id="detail" class="btn btn-sm btn-info" data-tooltip="tooltip" 
                      data-placement="bottom" title="Detail Laba" ><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i></a>
```

Note that if $penjualan->tanggal is null it will also throw that error.